# How to prove that $\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^2}+\dots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ using the spiral right angle triangle method?

Tags: calculus, geometry, summation, riemann-hypothesis, eulers-method

**I see this formula given below on [You tube video of mathologer channel](https://youtu.be/yPl64xi_ZZA) and then I try to find some new method to prove it**:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$$

I tried to prove it geometrically like this
[image: Reimann hypothesis]

***Our attempt***:

(1) First I tried to convert it in inverse trignometric form like this but that doesn't help much:
[image]

(2) In my second attempt I rotate the length of $1/2$ length from $1$ then I rotate $1/3$ length from remaining $1/2$ but that thing doesn't help us.

(3) In my third attempt, I tried to use coordinate geometry but that makes things more complex.

***My question***:How to prove that that summation of $1/n^2$ where $n$ tends to infinity is equal to $π^2/6$ by using ***spiral right angle triangle method***?

***EDIT***

NOTE: Sinc the last line segment Whose length ***tends to Square root of $π^2/6$ but not exactly equal to Square root of $π^2/6$ so it is probably not possible to solved it by using pure geometry***.
we understand that there must be ***needs of theory of Limit to prove it*** .
so we will also accept the solution which take the use of both concept means ***geometry with slight use of calculus.***

Comment: I am only aware of the approach with Fourier series to determine the value of this sum. Good luck for your method to work !

Comment: $1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n$
doesn't converge though, so the circumference of your circle will be infinite, won't it?

Comment: A thought: your spiral won’t converge to a point, since the outer edges are the harmonic series with infinite length. The radius will converge as you describe though, so the spiral should approach a circle from the inside and keep going round and round (albeit slowly)

Comment: After $n$ triangles you reach $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+i/f(k))$ with $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+1/[f(k)]^2)=\sum_{k=1}^n1/k^2$. You want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\prod_{k=1}^n(1+i/f(k))|=\pi/\sqrt{6}$. I can't see this being done without solving the Basel problem another way first.

Comment: @Peter, fourier method is already discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3412036/999691

Comment: You could alternate the direction at which you take the 90 degree turn, and then at least the triangle corners converge.

Comment: For a collection of (other) possible solutions see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @2'59'2 , Can you please provide me details information about how to rotate it by 90°? I don't understand your statement

Comment: @J.G. , you mean that it is impossible to  solved without using limits or calculus?  I was thinking that there could be some possibility to prove this by Euclidean geometry , Trigonometry or some extra construction ...

Comment: @Milten, You mean that Spiral will never stop? But after some more steps it seems like that line whose length is π^2/6 will stop there......, I mean it looks like that line segment will move but observer will feel that the line segment of length π^2/6 will stop

Comment: Whether $r$ converges is a separate question from whether $\theta$ converges, which is why my previous comment was careful to only talk about moduli or square moduli. However, I can't prove your strategy won't work.

Comment: Here is a non-fully-rigorous proof that your spiral will turn an infinite number of turns: $\arctan \frac{(1/(k+1)}{\sqrt{...}} \approx$ $\arctan \frac{1/(k+1)}{\sqrt{\pi^2/6}}\approx \frac{a}{k+1}$ where $a$ is a constant, but the sum of this series is infinite...

Comment: @JeanMarie, see here :https://www.dropbox.com/s/brprzxgahg731yt/1655387350765.jpg?dl=0 ,...., Sinc k approaches to infinity then last angle approaches to zero....may be i am wrong but can you verify it please

Comment: This is not contradictory with what I have written : harmonic series has its general term tending to 0 but its sum is infinite...

Comment: @JeanMarie , yes you are right that it is tending value and tends to zero but I don't understand about how you claim that line segment of √π^2/6 will turn infinite times? .....  , Because each times we are adding square of reciprocal of natural number then last line segment may be seems moving slowly

Comment: **Slowly but surely** arbitrarily large : (think to angles in radians), you will sooner or later exceed $2 \pi$, (one turn), then exceed $4 \pi$ (two turns), etc. maybe when you have 1 thousand terms or more...

Comment: @JeanMarie , Interesting but hard to imagine and thanks for clarifications

Comment: @JayendraandSankalp What I mean is, start at $(0,0)$ and go to $(1,0)$. Now you turn left 90 degrees and go to $\left(1,\frac12\right)$. But next, turn _right_. That is, move in a general clockwise direction $1/3$ of a unit, orthogonal to the vector $\left\langle 1,\frac12\right\rangle$. After that, move $1/4$ of a unit but now in a general _counter_-clockwise direction. Keep alternating the direction. Your radial lengths are still growing in the same way to $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$ but the angle of your position will converge now by a version of the alternating series test.

Comment: In the thread it seems that you may not be understanding how the radial length could stabilize even though the radius itself never stabilizes. Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jqlmdpwm4y) that may help. It is *not* the graph of the construction you are investigating, but it does demonstrate that same behavior.

Comment: @2'59'2, yes the idea was really great on going clockwise and anticlockwise sence then in imagination i think , if we do continuous clockwise and anticlockwise method as discussed by in your above message then we probably observed that line segment having length approaches √π^2/6 seems as oscillating ......, Thanks for the link of your graph as it helps me lot in understanding about how my construction will looks like

Comment: This is graph of the construction till $n=6400$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSt8E.png

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu , Can i paste your diagram in my question?

Comment: @Peter https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8337/815585

Comment: @JayendraandSankalp Here is a picture of the oscillating version with a few points in the sequence present. The outer circle has radius $\pi/\sqrt{6}$. https://imagebin.ca/v/6kzWdKaDOHfn

Comment: @FShrike , this same link is already mentioned by Dietrich Burde in above comment

Comment: @2'59'2 , in your construction , we take ***clockwise -antickockwise-clockwise-anticlockwise...*** Pattern which leads to *Oscillating line* similarly I was thinking to take lots of combination of Anticlockwise and clockwise sence....., In my construction i take continuously anticlockwise sence which gives spiral and change into Circle ....., Similarly if we take other combination like ***anticlock-antuclock, clockwise-clockwise-anticlock-anticlock***... types of combination then it will produce a line which will oscillates slowly than your construction..[continued]

Comment: And Such type of clockwise and anticlockwise construction gives more number of beautiful patterns....

Answer (score 1):

Since, using bgeneralized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1 {i^2}=H_k^{(2)}$$

quoting @Jean Marie *"your spiral will turn an infinite number of turns..."*
$$A_k=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(k+1) \sqrt{H_k^{(2)}}}\right)$$ which, for large $k$ is
$$A_k=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\pi  k}\Bigg[1-\frac{\pi ^2-3}{\pi ^2 k}+\frac{27-13 \pi ^2+2 \pi ^4}{2 \pi ^4
   k^2}-\frac{-135+90 \pi ^2-22 \pi ^4+2 \pi ^6}{2 \pi ^6
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \Bigg]$$

Repeating @Ivan Kaznacheyeu's calculations
$$\sum_{k=1}^{6400} A_k=6.678$$ while using the truncated series, we obtain $6.607$

In fact, computed exactly
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3857} A_k=2\pi +0.0000601086$$